# Transparency in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, transparency

When I want a window to be transparent I have to set AllowsTransparency to True.
When I set this the outer boarder(You know the close and minimize button and all) disappear also.
Oh, I am using Blend 3 to do this(Just got it, it's very nice).

Comment: Can you provide more details please

Comment: I updated the information, I guess this would be enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AllowsTransparency exists to facilitate the creation of ***non-rectangular windows***, and, consequently, when AllowsTransparency is set to true, a window's *WindowStyle property must be set to None*.

But still you can enable border by setting WindowStyle property.

*BTW: I love Blend 3, its awesome* I'm using it from last two weeks

Comment: But the AllowsTransparency will unchecked itself. It's like going in a loop, and yes Blend 3 is awesomeeeee.

Comment: Can't edit, it's like doing Photoshop but you can do it with your program :P

Comment: you check this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa358516.aspx sample for using AllowsTransparency